# Discord.py bot gives error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I have this tipbot that is working on the deposit function.

I have this code, which I am working on:

```
d2['data']['balances']['address']
embed=discord.Embed(description="{}".format(d2['data']['balances']['address']), color=0x00ff00)
await client.say(embed=embed)
```

Yet, after working on this, when I attempt to call the function from the bot, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What do I need to do to to fix the above code? (I was working on the first line of code.)

The json fragment that I was extracting is:

```
{'status': 'success', 'data': {'network': 'DOGE', 'available_balance': '0.0', 'pending_received_balance': '0.0', 'balances': [{'user_id': 1, 'label': 'shibe1', 'address': 'A9Bda9UMBcb1183PtsBxnbj5QgP6jwkCFG', 'available_balance': '0.00000000', 'pending_received_balance': '0.00000000'}]}}
```

Comment: `d2['data']['balances']` is a list.  You can't get `lst['address']`

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the fact that your JSON returns a list of addresses which, in this case, would mean what you're looking for is actually at `d2['data']['balances'][0]['address']` rather than `d2['data']['balances']['address']`.